# How to retrieve Oracle Key Performance Indicators in 5 minute intervals within a time range

Tags: oracle, performance, performance-testing

I have Oracle 11g attached to a Performance Test environment. A performance test runs for two hours. After the run I want to programmatically extract a variety of in key indicators from the database to store with the results.

What commands would I run before and after the test to collect key indicators, ideally grouped in 5 minute totals.

- CPU
- Memory
- Total SQL requests
- Logical IO
- Physical IO

And bottleneck indicators, (various waits for locks and latches).

I will accept a handy link to an article or a collection of useful SQL commands to explore.

Comment: Use AWR reports. You'll be wanting a diagnostics pack licence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query runs on 11.1.0.7 Enterprise and provides similar results to the the OEM Grid performance page which requires the diagnostics package. There is a certain irony to running this script through SQL Server reporting services which is beyond the scope of this question.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SAMPLE_TIME, 'HH24:MI ') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
       ROUND(OTHER / 60, 3) AS OTHER,
       ROUND(CLUST / 60, 3) AS CLUST,
       ROUND(QUEUEING / 60, 3) AS QUEUEING,
       ROUND(NETWORK / 60, 3) AS NETWORK,
       ROUND(ADMINISTRATIVE / 60, 3) AS ADMINISTRATIVE,
       ROUND(CONFIGURATION / 60, 3) AS CONFIGURATION,
       ROUND(COMMIT / 60, 3) AS COMMIT,
       ROUND(APPLICATION / 60, 3) AS APPLICATION,
       ROUND(CONCURRENCY / 60, 3) AS CONCURRENCY,
       ROUND(SIO / 60, 3) AS SYSTEM_IO,
       ROUND(UIO / 60, 3) AS USER_IO,
       ROUND(SCHEDULER / 60, 3) AS SCHEDULER,
       ROUND(CPU / 60, 3) AS CPU,
       ROUND(BCPU / 60, 3) AS BACKGROUND_CPU
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SAMPLE_TIME, 'MI') AS SAMPLE_TIME,
               DECODE(SESSION_STATE,
                      'ON CPU',
                      DECODE(SESSION_TYPE, 'BACKGROUND', 'BCPU', 'ON CPU'),
                      WAIT_CLASS) AS WAIT_CLASS
          FROM V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY
         WHERE SAMPLE_TIME > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1'
         HOUR
           AND SAMPLE_TIME <= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MI')) ASH PIVOT(COUNT(*) 
  FOR WAIT_CLASS IN('ON CPU' AS CPU,'BCPU' AS BCPU,
'Scheduler' AS SCHEDULER,
'User I/O' AS UIO,
'System I/O' AS SIO, 
'Concurrency' AS CONCURRENCY,                                                                               
'Application' AS  APPLICATION,                                                                                  
'Commit' AS  COMMIT,                                                                             
'Configuration' AS CONFIGURATION,                     
'Administrative' AS   ADMINISTRATIVE,                                                                                 
'Network' AS  NETWORK,                                                                                 
'Queueing' AS   QUEUEING,                                                                                  
'Cluster' AS   CLUST,                                                                                      
'Other' AS  OTHER))
ORDER BY 1
```

This query is not as good as what Grid displays but it's close.
[image: SSRS report] [image: OEM Grid]

Comment: Please bear in mind that you query  V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY which requires diagnostic pack, as per  [Oracle Dokumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/options.htm#DBLIC177)

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot without any fancy licenses or third-party tools would be STATSPACK/PERFSTAT.

It comes with you Oracle Installation, the documentation can be found in $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/spdoc.txt (Checked with 12.1.0.2 and 11.2.0.4).
It does not generate fancy graphics it's text only.

You might want to  try [oraSASH](http://pioro.github.io/orasash) with simulates ASH (hence  the name) , so the scripts for ASH might work. Did not work with oraSASH myself so check carefully yourself.